# #vim: set only sort of working

Tags: vim, modeline

I have `.zsh-theme` files (from `oh-my-zsh`), but they are not syntax highlighted.  I was able to get this done pretty easily with

```
autocmd BufEnter *.zsh-theme set filetype=sh
```

However, before I did that I tried adding a vim meta comment for a specific file

```
#vim: set filetype=sh
```

The addition of the `#` apparently makes vim detect the file as a `conf` file, but it seems that this command is ignored (i.e. it is *not* detected as a `sh` file in spite of the comment).  Is there any reason this may be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get rid of the word set (and add a space after the comment symbol)

```
# vim: filetype=sh
```

This fits with the first form of modelines

```
There are two forms of modelines.  The first form:
        [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}

[text]                  any text or empty
{white}                 at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|ex:}          the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
[white]                 optional white space
{options}               a list of option settings, separated with white space
                        or ':', where each part between ':' is the argument
                        for a ":set" command (can be empty)
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for this type of modeline is:

```
[text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]
```

That is, try adding a space before `vim:`, and a trailing colon:

```
# vim: set filetype=sh:
```

You can find everything about modelines in

- [`:h modeline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline)
- [`:h 'modeline'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27modeline%27)

Comment: @FDinoff Hmm, isn't that just part of the syntax (I don't know why)? Also see the examples given in the help, `/* vim: set ai tw=75: */` ...